# Set permission with aws object using transferobserver android

Tags: android, amazon-s3

```
private void beginUpload(String filePath) {
        if (filePath == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not find the filepath of the selected file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        File file = new File(filePath);
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, file.getName(), file);
        observers.add(observer);
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         Util.fillMap(map, observer, false);
        transferRecordMaps.add(map);
        observer.setTransferListener(new UploadListener());
        simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Permission with  `PutObjectRequest` on your current bucket and file like [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/63)

```
if(this.publicRead)
{
    por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
}
```